# I can ssh to the server but port is not listed as open

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall

I can easily ssh to the server using `ssh dev@1.2.3.4 -p 42912`

But from inside the server if I run `sudo netstat -tulpn` I get:
[image]

Why the port 42912 is not listed?

Comment: Is there a NAT device or router in between that is forwarding external port 42912 to the server's ssh port 22?

Comment: I don't know, I did not create the server. Is there a way to check this?

Comment: Well, is `1.2.3.4` the private LAN IP address of the server, or something else?

Comment: 1.2.3.4 is a public IP

Answer (score 0):

Your router port 42912 is open to the public network on address 1.2.3.4

The router forwards SSH traffic from this port to your server's LAN interface, where your SSH server is listening on the default port 22.